# recyclerview search filter is not working?

Tags: android, search, filter, android-recyclerview

i have coded `getFilter()` in adapter class and `setOnQueryTextListener` in mainactivity but don't know whats the prob it is not filtering nor searching please help I need to implement a search filter RecyclerView the list must be filtered while typing.

//adapter class

```
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Menus> menusList;
    private List<Menus> menusFilteredList;

    public MenuAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Menus> menusList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.menusList = menusList;
    }


    @Override
    public MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);
        return new MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Menus menus = menusList.get(position);

        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(menus.getMenuimage())
                .into(holder.menuimage);


        holder.menuname.setText(menus.getMenuname());
        holder.cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(menus.getMenubg()));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText(mCtx, "" + menus.getMenuname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                if (menus.getMenuurl().getBytes().length == 0)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Not Available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent web = new Intent(mCtx,WebActivity.class);
                    web.putExtra("url",menus.getMenuurl());
                    web.putExtra("urltitle",menus.getMenuname());
                    mCtx.startActivity(web);
                    ((Activity)mCtx).finish();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menusFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    menusFilteredList = menusList;

                } else {

                   // List<Menus> filteredList = new List<>();
                    List<Menus> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Menus menus : menusList) {

                        if (menus.getMenuname().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || menus.getMenuurl().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(menus);
                        }
                    }

                    menusFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = menusFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                menusList = (ArrayList<Menus>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView menuimage;
        TextView menuname;
        CardView cardview;

        public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            menuimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
            menuname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuname);
            cardview  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

        }

    }
}
```

//mainactivity

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    search(searchView);
    return true;

}

private void search(SearchView searchView) {

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: its working now the problem is with the listener

Answer (score 0):

you suppose to set count value also

```
 @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(menusList);
        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

           for (Menus menus : menusList) {

                    if (menus.getMenuname().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || menus.getMenuurl().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                        filteredList.add(menus);
                    }
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Count Number " + filteredList.size());
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }
```

Please note: filtered list should loaded with all list item at initial stage only in the adapter

Comment: doenst filtered